# jQuery Colorpicker change value on click out

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

I am using this jQuery Colorpicker http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#about

Is there any way I can make it change the value(*color code) of the input on click out of the colorpicker?

Now it submits the color picked only by clicking the submit button on the Colorpicker.

```
    <input type="text" value="#FFFFFF">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      $('input').ColorPicker({
          onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
              $(el).val('#' + hex);
              $(el).ColorPickerHide();
          },
          onBeforeShow: function () {
              $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
          }
      })
      .bind('keyup', function(){
          $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
      });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, what you want to change?

Comment: I want to change the color code from input. I will update my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't find a good way, but here's an ugly though hopefully not entirely bad way of doing it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var $pickerInput;
  $('input').ColorPicker({ 
      onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
          $(el).val('#' + hex);
          $(el).ColorPickerHide();
      },
      onBeforeShow: function () {
          $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
          $pickerInput = $(this);
      },
      onHide: function(picker) {
          $pickerInput.val('#' + $(picker).find('.colorpicker_hex input').val());
      }
  })
  .bind('keyup', function(){
      $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to work. I don't see any error in the console though.

Comment: Strange. What browser are you using? Here's a JSFiddle of it which works for me. You'll need to have visited http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ first though, to cache the plugin files. http://jsfiddle.net/9a5eR/

Comment: Weird indeed, your example is working very nice. I am testing in Chrome, yours works but mine doesn't

Comment: Oh, sorry, I naively assumed the picker control would always be rendered as an adjacent sibling of the input control so my example only works because there only one input on the page. Let me have another look!

Comment: I've updated my answer with something less bad, which will work with more than one input on the page. Sorry, don't know what I was thinking. Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/9a5eR/1/

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? You can access the hex information in the onChange event and assign it to some hidden element, in this case I've added a second input. Then, onHide, you take the value of the hidden element and assign it to the current input box.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="hexVal" type="text" value="#FFFFFF">
<input id="hidden" type="text" value="#FFFFFF">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#hexVal').ColorPicker({
        onSubmit: function (hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
            $(el).val('#' + hex);
            $(el).ColorPickerHide();
        },
        onBeforeShow: function () {
            $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
        },
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
            $('#hidden').val('#' + hex);
        },
        onHide: function (picker) {
            $('#hexVal').val($('#hidden').val());
        }
    })
        .bind('keyup', function () {
        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8hUxt/1/).

Comment: Thank. I have many inputs like these, so this doesn't really works for me.

Comment: Ah, sorry - didn't realise. Glad you got it sorted with the other answer!